# How many features of given image

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

assume that I have a set of image and segmented image of a object in image (training set). Now, I want to measure features of object in image based on the training data. But I don't know how many features in image. And which is best feature for image segmentation? Gradient feature or entropy feature or ....Could you explain help me ?

Comment: When you say *I don't know how many features are in an image*, this makes no sense. Images don't have features inherently. You, as an engineer, select features you want to extract from images. Can you elaborate on this point?

Comment: @Phonon: It means that image has many features ex mean, std, edge,...But which is more popular for image classification?